# Return results from two tables in WordPress database

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have these two tables:

**lic_key_tbl**

```
name    license_key     email
----------------------------------------
john    95g12dhp0       john@example.com
cath    bdjagdlo8       cath@example.org
john    8nawjdcms       john@example.com
alex    mhi79y32p       alex@alex.com
```

**lic_reg_domain_tbl**

```
lic_key     registered_domain
-----------------------------
95g12dhp0   google.com
8nawjdcms   abc.com
bdjagdlo8   microsoft.com
mhi79y32p   facebook.com
```

Basically I am trying to display a list of registered domains that belong to the current logged in user (in this example scenario, pretend I am logged in as john@example.com) by comparing the matching license keys from each table.

I know this code is incomplete...

```
/* User info */
global $userdata;
$user_info              = get_userdata($user_ID);
$user_email             = $userdata->user_email;

/* DB table names */
global $wpdb;
$lic_key_table          = $wpdb->prefix . 'lic_key_tbl';
$lic_reg_domain_table   = $wpdb->prefix . 'lic_reg_domain_tbl';

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $lic_reg_domain_table);

foreach ( $results as $result ) { ?>

    <li>
        <?php echo $result->registered_domain; ?>
    </li>

<?php } 
?>
```

...but if I am logged in as john@example.com, then the results I see should be:

```
google.com
abc.com
```

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection attacks.

```
global $userdata;
$user_info              = get_userdata($user_ID);
$user_email             = $userdata->user_email;

$login_name             = $userdata->user_login;
$nicename             = $userdata->user_nicename;

/* DB table names */
global $wpdb;
$lic_key_table          = $wpdb->prefix . 'lic_key_tbl';
$lic_reg_domain_table   = $wpdb->prefix . 'lic_reg_domain_tbl';


//get the registered_domain based on a related column (license_key and lic_key) between them. and check if email is equal to current login use email
$sql =  "
    SELECT *
    FROM $lic_reg_domain_table d, $lic_key_table k  
    WHERE k.license_key = d.lic_key and k.email =%s 
    ";

// Prepare the SQL statement so the string input gets escaped for security.
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $user_email );

$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Comment: This works - thanks! One thing I didn't think of though. In the `lic_reg_domain_tbl` there is also a column called `item_reference` and I'd like to be able to `echo $result->item_reference;` but it doesn't seem to work. How can I get the item_reference as well?